# WebSocket Reconnect issue on network disconnection

Tags: c#, sockets

i am using below socket functions to receive data from socket server, when i disconnect my network connection , and reconnect again socket application stop receiving data. I also tried to add a timer which check the state of socket every 20 sec but its not working. Any advise?

```
private WebSocket client;  //before form_load

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new WebSocket(host);

    client.OnOpen += (ss, ee) =>
      {
         MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Connected to {0} successfully ", host));
      };

    client.OnError += (ss, ee) =>
      {
         MessageBox.Show("     Error: " + ee.Message);
      };

    client.OnMessage += (ss, ee) =>
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Message: " + ee.Message);
      };

    client.OnClose += (ss, ee) =>
      {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Disconnected with {0}", host));   
    };

    client.Connect();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(client.ReadyState.ToString()=="Closed")
       {
          client.Close();
          client = new WebSocket(host);
          client.Connect();
       }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the web socket library/package you used. Here is a simple working reconnect example using WebSocket4Net.

Because of AutoSendPing it closes the connection when something happens to the network and timer tries to reconnect if the socket is closed.

```
private WebSocket client;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new WebSocket(host)
    {
        EnableAutoSendPing = true,
        AutoSendPingInterval = 10,
    };

    client.Opened += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connected");
    };

    client.Error += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error {ee.Exception}");
    };

    client.MessageReceived += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Message: {ee.Message}");
    };

    client.Closed += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Disconnected");
    };

    client.Open();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (client.State == WebSocketState.Closed)
    {
        client.Open();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Trying to reconnect by timer");
    }
}
```